# How to get the Metrics for App Service Environment (by Azure Monitor)?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt, app-service-environment

I am trying to get the metrics for the App Service Environment, i.e. Scale Actions Initiated, Observed Capacity/Metric Value, but the graphs are all empty. I am a bit confused if App Service Plan is the only to go or not...
 [image: Azure Montiro Metrics for the ASE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the support ticket, MSFT has a third party provider for the monitoring, and they do not provide this functionality -yet- (also due to low usage/high cost of ASE). They suggested to monitor each resource in Service Plan separately.

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been brought to our attention. The PG is working on a solution. In the meantime, please refer to workaround provided [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19756). Thanks

Comment: That issue is related, but tiny bit different, she could not get to this graph, i.e. it does not list ASE, but my problem is even if I got some metrics, they are not monitored...